# Moodle how to edit javascript files?

Tags: javascript, open-source, moodle

I'm working with moodle open source code. It is running on my machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and apache2 as explained on their installation guide. My problem occurs when i change a javascript file, the code changed does not appear updated on the browser (chrome dev tools). Even if i delete the file, browser continue to show me the file code in the source tree (after refresh, and clearing the broser cache). Am I missing a step, on this edition of javascript files in Moodle structure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is cached - you need to [purge all site caches](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Purge_all_cache) to see changes. If debugging is off and you are using an AMD module (as all modern Moodle javascript does) or a YUI module (as used by older Moodle code), then you will need to use [grunt](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Grunt) to to minify the javascript before it can be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @davosmith! Since you work with moodle, is it possible to capture all ajax requests before they execute, without having to modify all the javascript code that makes the requests?

Comment: Older AJAX requests go to arbitrary end points, so no. Newer AJAX calls in Moodle all go through a standard location and use webservices. I can't tell you the location off the top of my head.

Comment: davosmith when I want to debug js codes in amd module its too hard to purge all site caches in each edit is there any way for debuging?